# Kafka for API gateway to store messages

Tags: rest, apache-kafka, api-gateway

I need to build a secure REST API for different services where client services can post and receive messages from other clients( like mail box. but messages are going to be in JSON form. and should be persistent. I am expecting around 5000 client services. With around 50 message per service per day).
My questions are:

1. Can I use Kafka for this(I think I will be needing some wrapper over
   Kafka to manage other task) ?
2. If yes then outbox and inbox are going to be a separate topic for
   each service?( 2 topics per service. 5000*2 topics. My plan is to
   create them dynamically as new client joins in)
3. what are the alternative technologies to write this kind of gateway.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you use a regular RDBMS for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Kafka to implement REST API because REST API implies request/response while Kafka is just a message queue (Kafka doesn't provide a mechanism to respond to messages). You can use Kafka to produce messages to be consumed by other services. The idea of message queues is to decouple producer from consumer and vice versa. When a consumer receives a message it acts on it, that's it. But when you say inbox/outbox you imply that there's a response for a message which means that producers and consumers pace should be similar which couples them which is against the nature of message queues.

It seems like in your case it makes more sense to use http requests/response or even websockets. If you want to save the request/response data (making it persistent) you can save it either in a database, object storage (like [S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/)), [log it](https://newrelic.com/lp/products/log-monitoring) or send each message to Kafka so that Kafka stores all of your messages, writes to Kafka will actually be very fast because Kafka is roughly-speaking an append-only log. You can then search messages values using [ksqldb](https://ksqldb.io).